# Accessing External Data Reference attributes in core data image

Tags: ios, swift, image, core-data

**Explanation:**

I have an entity in core data that takes a name, a text field, and an image as attributes.  Sometimes, the image will be set to nil, so I would like to check for this.  `if item.image == nil` did not seem to work, so I have tried printing `item.image` to the console to see why.  I notice that I get the **Output** below and that for items that have no image the `path` is `nil`, but for items with an image, the path is something else.  Therefore, my thought is that if I can get the `path` from the External Data Reference output, then I can do `if item.image.ExternalDataReferencePath == nil` and accomplish desired `if` statement.  Does anyone know how I can get the `path` in the External Data Reference below to check if it is nil?

**Objective:** Get the "path" for the External Data Reference so that I can check if it is nil.

**Problem:** I have tried accessibilityPath, but this does not seem to be the right thing since it returns nil for all items (both ones with images and ones without).

**Code:**

```
for item in (frc.fetchedObjects)! { 
   print("items fetched. testing \(item.name), myField2 \(item.myField2), whose image is")
                        print(item.image!)
}
```

**Output:**

```
items fetched. testing Optional("my name 1"), myField2 Optional("1"), whose image is    
External Data Reference: <self = 0x1702940f0 ; path = nil ; length = 13127>

items fetched. testing Optional("my Name 2"), myField2 Optional("1"), whose image is
    External Data Reference: <self = 0x170294140 ; path = 735DB08E-2727-4F01-91C9-914C8A3DD170 ; length = 6826295>
```

Comment: Is your `image` attribute set to "optional" in the `xcdatamodeld` file?

Comment: @RyanH. I believe so since I am able to initialize it to nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an update for others that stumble upon this in the future, here is a workaround. I added an attribute to my entity which set it equal to `false` whenever I create a new item.  Then I set the attribute to `true` anytime the function to add an image is called.  This makes it fairly easy to create the for loop below:

```
    for item in (frc.fetchedObjects)! { 
       if item.photoAdded == true {
          //image was added
       } else {
          //no image was added
       }
    }
```